# How to configure nested layout in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, layout

I have a base layout in /views/layouts/application.html.haml

```
%html
  %head
    = stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all"
    = javascript_include_tag "application"
    = csrf_meta_tags
  %body
    = render 'layouts/header'
    = yield
    = render 'layouts/footer'
```

In all my views rendered, it inherits from the above with the header and footer.

How can I render a page that doesn't inherit from /views/layouts/application ? Or just render partially by omitting the header and footer, but still include the stylesheet and javascript?

Answer (score 1):

You could render the header and footer for all views except a specific view by checking the `controller_name` and `action_name`. e.g

```
%html
  %head
    = stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all"
    = javascript_include_tag "application"
    = csrf_meta_tags
  %body
    = render 'layouts/header' unless controller_name == 'CONTROLLER' && action_name == 'ACTION'
    = yield
    = render 'layouts/footer' unless controller_name == 'CONTROLLER' && action_name == 'ACTION'
```

So if you put `users` instead of CONTROLLER and `show` instead of ACTION the header and footer would not display for the user's show action.